# rabbitmq keepalive timeout error

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq, keep-alive

Below is part of my rabbitmq log file.

=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Dec-2016::09:36:20 ===
closing MQTT connection "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11030 -> xx.xx.xx.xx:1884" (keepalive timeout)

=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Dec-2016::09:36:20 ===
closing MQTT connection "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:14653 -> xx.xx.xx.xx:1884" (keepalive timeout)

=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Dec-2016::09:36:22 ===
closing MQTT connection "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:14494 -> xx.xx.xx.xx:1884" (keepalive timeout)

I think this is closing MQTT connection by keepalive timeout.
Is this normal?
These are repeatedly shown. so log disk is full.
Is there way of connection is keep alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clients are failing to send something within the keep alive time
they specified when they connected to the broker. See [MQTT specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html)
section 3.1.2.10 Keep Alive.
Compliant clients would send a PINGREQ to keep the connection alive.